# How to add event to my CustomCell in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols, custom-cell

I have a UITableView which has rows which include two UISwitch buttons. Until I upgraded to Xcode8 it worked with me adding a protocol to the view controller like this

```
protocol CustomCellDelegator {
    func callSegueFromCell()
}
```

Then I added the following to my CustomCell swift file which handles the outlets for my custom cell.

```
open class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate:CustomCellDelegator!

    @IBOutlet weak var uidLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var operatedSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var switchRTN: UISwitch!

    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBAction func operatedSwitchChange() {
        if operatedSwitch.isOn {
            AppDelegate.myGlobalVars.gSwitchType = "OpsOn"
        }
        else {
            AppDelegate.myGlobalVars.gSwitchType = "OpsOff"
        }
        if(self.delegate != nil){ //Just to be safe.
            self.delegate.callSegueFromCell()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func rtnSwitchChange() {
        if switchRTN.isOn {
            AppDelegate.myGlobalVars.gSwitchType = "RtnOn"
        }
        else {
            AppDelegate.myGlobalVars.gSwitchType = "RtnOff"
        }
        if(self.delegate != nil){ //Just to be safe.
            self.delegate.callSegueFromCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Until I upgraded this worked and delegate always had a value, now it is always nil and the segue is never called.

What do i need to do differently since I upgraded to get this working again?

Comment: Can you show the relative parts of your View Controller, which contains the code, that sets and conforms to the delegate?

Comment: I know I need to assign delegate to my cell (cell.delegate = ??) in  cellForRowAtIndexPath but I can't get it to work as cell.delegate = CustomCellDelegator throws an error as it is of type CustomCellDelegator.protocol. Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer below. You provide another class or type, that conforms to the Protocol. It must be an instance of something, so that you can actually perform any code with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've assigned your delegate in the ViewController:

```
// Make your ViewController conform to the protocol
class MyViewController: CustomCellDelegator {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell            
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func callSegueFromCell() {
      // perform your segue here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, adding CustomCellDelegator to my ViewController delegate helped me to assign my cell.delegate = self.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You assign your delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the cell.
Also, I would recommend to keep `weak` reference to the delegate.

```
protocol CustomCellDelegator: class {
    func callSegueFromCell()
}
```

In your `CustomTableViewCell` replace

```
var delegate:CustomCellDelegator!
```

with

```
weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegator?
```

After this you do not need to check if Your delegate is `nil` or not, your app will not crash.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I made these changes but delegate is still nil

Comment: show us please where are you assigning the delegate to your cell.

Comment: At the moment I'm not which you are correct in assuming is the problem. I've tried cell.delegate = CustomCellDelegator which fails  because it is of type CustomCellDelegator.protocol. How do I assign the delegate?